# Mockito thenReturn not working in RichSourceFunction

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mockito, apache-flink

In my unit test I am mocking the return of my Fetcher then passing it into the constructor of a nested static class Head.Source. My Fetcher gets items every 5 minutes.

The problem is that in each call of fetcher.getItems() in my Source.run(), it is returning NullPointerException (not the items I set in the mock) because it is stepping through my getItems() method which tries to access a field that is null (it's null since Fetcher is a mocked class). How can I fix this test so that when fetcher.getItems() gets called, it does not try to execute it and just returns what I specified in my thenReturn?

Also, I used a debugger and found that in the Source constructor, my mock is working (fetcher.getItems() is returning the items I specified) but once I call fetcher.getItems() in the run(), it returns NullPointerException

```
public static class Source extends RichSourceFunction<Set<Integer>> {
    private boolean isRunning;
    private final Fetcher fetcher;
    public Source(final Fetcher fetcher) {
      this.fetcher = fetcher;
      this.isRunning = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(SourceContext<Set<Integer>> ctx) throws Exception {
      while (this.isRunning) {
        try {
          Set<Integer> items = fetcher.getItems();
          if (items != null) {
            ctx.collect(items);
          }
          TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(300000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println("exception");
        }
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void cancel() {
      this.isRunning = false;
    }
  }
```

This is my unit test. I have mocked the fetcher so it will get a different set of items between the first and second call of getItems()

```
@Test
  public void testSource() throws Exception {
    Fetcher mockFetcher = Mockito.mock(Fetcher.class);
    Set<Integer> items1 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1, 3, 5));
    Set<Integer> items2 = new HashSet<>(Collections.singletonList(7));
    Mockito.when(mockFetcher.getItems())
        .thenReturn(items1)
        .thenReturn(items2);
    Head.Source source = new Head.Source(mockFetcher);
    DataStream<Set<Integer>> items = env.addSource(source);
    Iterator<Set<Integer>> iterator = items.executeAndCollect();
    Iterable<Set<Integer>> iterable = () -> iterator;
    List<Set<Integer>> collectedItems =
        StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false).collect(Collectors.toList());
    Assert.assertEquals(2, collectedItems.size());
  }
```

Comment: Your test never calls `Source#run` … What does `env.addSource` do?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the full stack trace of the exception.

Answer (score 2):

Flink source functions (like other funtions) are serialized and then deserialized before being run. So wondering if you have to make your Mock serializable, as per [this](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/5.11.0/org/mockito/MockSettings.html#serializable()).